# Jboss EAP 7.1, standalone.xml, using IBM MQ, no outbound / outgoing message: can urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters-section be empty?

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq

Jboss EAP 7.1, `standalone.xml`, using IBM MQ, no outbound / no outgoing message

Is it right that `standalone.xml` / `urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters-section` can be empty, if my application has no outgoing messages (only reads messages from MQ) ?

Comment: Have you tried it?  The IBM MQ RA is just a `rar` file that contains all of the IBM MQ classes that applications use to connect to IBM MQ, it normally would be used both for sending and receiving messages as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Is it right that standalone.xml / urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters-section can be empty, if my application has no outgoing messages (only reads messages from MQ) ?

-> No, wmq.jmsra.rar has to be configured:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>LocalTransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the standalone-full.xml.  The standalone.xml configuration does not include JMS messaging.  The embedded JMS broker in JBoss can be disabled (if desired) by providing an empty configuration for ActiveMQ.